# Flash AS3 - MC Enter Frame and Advance to next frame of Root

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a series of MCs in my root timeline.
On each frame in the root, I am simply running 'stop();' to allow the MC within the frame to play through all the way.
Once the timeline within the MC reaches the last frame, I have the following AS to go back to the root and play the next frame (each frame is labelled):

```
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playSecondSeries);

    function playSecondSeries(e:Event):void {
      (root as MovieClip).gotoAndPlay("secondSeries");  // secondSeries is the frame  name back at root
    }

    stop();
```

I thought this would be straight-forward, but when I go to compile, the animation actually plays fine, however I receive an endless loop of the following Output error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>       at myMovie_fla::txtMask_1_9/playSecondSeries()

The loop of this error is bogging everything down until the movie basically comes to a halt.  I'm on a tight deadline and just going in circles.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the last frame of each MC animation, put the following script:

```
(root as MovieClip).gotoAndPlay("yourRootNextFrameLabel");
stop(); // optional
```

It should work fine, however code is still ugly. I'd recommend checking other solutions, e.g. [TimelineLite](http://www.greensock.com/timelinelite/).

Comment: thanks, basically i was over-thinking things by adding the addEventListener, when all i needed was to run the content of the function i was calling.